# Double backslash under Linux bash

Tags: java, windows, bash

In the Linux bash to identify a Windows folder I have to use double backslash for example  `"java -jar myjar.jar C:\\Users\\username"` while in the Windows command prompt does not need, just  `"java -jar myjar.jar C:\Users\username"`, is it normal?

Comment: The double backslash is treated like an escape character to prevent issues with string formatting.

Comment: Yes, that's normal. In bash you could also use single quotes, then you wouldn't have to escape ``\ `` with another `\ `.

Comment: See [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) in the manual.

Comment: Bash and cmd.exe are two separate shells with separate languages using separate syntax, yes.

Comment: If you're running bash on Windows, you can probably still use Linux `/` forward slash instead of Windows ``\`` backslash in file names, since bash *is* a ported Linux command.

Comment: I'm not using bash on Windows, I've written a SOAP Web services that returns information about remote folders.

Comment: Yes. It's worth noting however that Windows CLI will know what you mean if you use a forward slash. So if looking at `C:\\Users\\Somebody` bothers you, you can pass `C:/Users/Somebody` in bash no problem.

Comment: @KuboMD, many Windows programs use forward-slash for optional arguments (switches) and do not support using forward slash in unquoted paths. It's usually fine if the path is quoted in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the backslash is used for newlines and special characters in bash. But since Windows uses backslashes in file paths, it does not need a double backslash.